# How many numbers from 1 through 60100 are divisible by none of the numbers from 2 through 6?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My thoughts on doing this problem:

total numbers is 60100

so from the total I subtract the numbers divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

Yet my answer

60100-30050-20033-15025-12020-10016

is a negative number. How to solve this problem?

Comment: All of the numbers divisible by $4$ are divisible by $2$. The numbers divisible by $6$ are also numbers divisible by both $2$ and $3$. So your far "over-counting" the numbers to subtract.

Comment: Related: [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). See how some  numbers get crossed out several times.

Comment: No full solution, just a hint: You counted some of them twice in building the difference.
Note that for example all the 15025 numbers that are divisible by 4 are divisible by 2, too, so you should skip counting those again within the 30050 numbers that are divisible by 2. Similar for 6 with 3 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to consider the primes only.

The number of Numbers divisible by at least one of $2,3,5$ will be $$\left\lfloor\frac{60100}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{60100}3\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{60100}5\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{60100}{2\cdot3}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{60100}{2\cdot5}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{60100}{3\cdot5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{60100}{2\cdot3\cdot5}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: It might be good to mumble the words "inclusion-exclusion" where if $A$ is the event "divisible by $2$", $B$ is the event "divisible by $3$", and $C$ is the event "divisible by $5$", then $N(A\; \text{or}\; B\; \text{or}\; C) = N(A) + N(B) + N(C) - N(A\; \text{and}\; B) - N(A\; \text{and}\; C) - N(B\; \text{and}\; C) + N(A\; \text{and}\; B\; \text{and}\; C)$ (since the event that a number is divisible by a number in $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ is the same as the event that it is divisible by one of $2, 3, 5$). Anyway, +1.

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer, we just now subtract this total from 60100.

Comment: @user43208, thanks for pointing out the term (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add to that negative number the numbers divisible by (2*3), (2*4), (2*5), (2*6),
(3*4), (3*5), (3*6), (4*5), (4*6) and (5*6) as you are subtracting them twice

and subtract again the numbers divisible by (2*3*4),(2*3*5)...(all combinations of 3 numbers)
because you are adding them three times, hence is like if you had not subtracted none of them at the beggining

then add all combinations of 4

and finally subtract (2*3*4*5*6)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as pointed out by others, you need only eliminate numbers divisible by $2,3,5$

How many numbers between $1$ and $30$ are indivisible by these numbers?

If you add $30$ to such an indivisible number, does its indivisible status change?

How many sets of $30$ numbers are there between $1$ and $60090$?

Can you check the numbers from $60091$ to $60100$ by hand?